# Как создать и использовать из приложения простейшую БД?

Tags: база-данных, sql, visual-c++

Никогда раннее не сталкивался с *СУБД*, однако немного знаком с языком *SQL*. Стоит задача написать программку, взаимодействующую с простой *БД*, содержащей таблицу из 4-ёх колонок. Дайте направление, какое вообще ПО использовать, как это ПО использовать в *VC++2010*(требуется именно эта среда). В какую вообще сторону копать?

Answer (score 1):

Традиционно (с 90х) -- msjet. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine и http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966378.aspx . Ну а подробнее -- msdn